# go net/rpc rpc call get Inconsistency between the sent reply and the received reply

Tags: go, rpc

i am trying to learn rpc of go, using a example like this:
FOR SREVER RPC DEFNITION:

```
func (m *Master) HandleGetTask(args *GetTaskArgs, reply *GetTaskReply) error {
    m.mu.Lock()
    defer m.mu.Unlock()
    if !m.mapDoneBool {
        select {
        case taskId := <-m.mapTaskChann:
            {
                reply.WorkerNum = taskId
                reply.nMapTasksTotal = m.nMapTasksNum
                reply.nReduceTasksTotal = m.nReduceTasksNum
                reply.GetTaskType = MapTask
                reply.GetTaskFileName = m.mapFiles[taskId]
                m.mapTaskIssueTime[taskId] = time.Now()
                log.Printf("reply is like %v", reply)
            }
        case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
            {
                reply.WorkerNum = -1
                reply.GetTaskType = UnknownTask
                reply.GetTaskFileName = "unknown file"
                reply.nMapTasksTotal = m.nMapTasksNum
                reply.nReduceTasksTotal = m.nReduceTasksNum

            }
        }
```

FOR CLIENT RPC CALL:

```
func CallGetTask() GetTaskReply {
    args := &GetTaskArgs{}
    reply := new(GetTaskReply)
    ret := call("Master.HandleGetTask", args, reply)
    if !ret {
        log.Println("Call Get Task error")
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    return *reply
}
```

FOR STRUCT DEFINITION:

```
type TaskType int

const (
    UnknownTask TaskType = 0
    MapTask     TaskType = 1
    ReduceTask  TaskType = 2
    Done        TaskType = 3
)

type GetTaskArgs struct{}

type GetTaskReply struct {
    WorkerNum         int
    nMapTasksTotal    int
    nReduceTasksTotal int
    GetTaskType       TaskType
    GetTaskFileName   string
}
```

FOR SERVER REGISTER:

```
func (m *Master) server() {
    rpc.Register(m)
    rpc.HandleHTTP()
    l, e := net.Listen("tcp", ":1234")
    // sockname := masterSock()
    // os.Remove(sockname)
    // log.Printf("Listening on %v", sockname)
    //l, e := net.Listen("unix", sockname)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("listen error:", e)
    }
    go http.Serve(l, nil)
}
```

ISSUE:
as log shown, client """EXPECTED""" result is like:
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jY8i.png)
however, i get a error result by log shown:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/727h4.png)
PROBLEM is: why client received is different with server sent
By the way, i use tcpdump to get the rpc packet, and find data package is same as client received.
Has go rpc's encoder(GOB) any bugs?

Comment: ["package `encoding/gob` is used to transport the data"](https://pkg.go.dev/net/rpc#pkg-overview) and ["Structs encode and decode only exported fields"](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/gob#hdr-Types_and_Values). `nMapTasksTotal` and `nReduceTasksTotal` are not exported, so they will not be included.